# How to call a certain method in each action method of all controller classes in Magento?

Tags: model-view-controller, magento, redirect, controller

For a Magento shop I'm working on I have to check certain session variables on each load of a page. When the variables don't have the expected values I need to redirect to certain page.

No I wonder how I could implement such a behavior. Normally I would do the check in action methods of each controller, but I don't want to rewrite each controller or all their base classes.

Is there a easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento's event architecture to the rescue! Observe the `controller_action_predispatch` method.

**Edit**: Note that this event is dispatched in both adminhtml and frontend, so Sergy's answer is important - configure the event observer under the appropriate area.

Answer (score 5):

Yes,
you can always use magento events in this case:
 1. `controller_action_postdispatch`. 
 2. `controller_action_predispatch` . 
Be careful: same events are used in admin area also.

Comment: A very good point! Configure your event observer under the frontend event area.